# upload files by using FILE-URI distination to firebase storage in Ionic 2

Tags: firebase, upload, ionic2, local, firebase-storage

Is possible to upload files such as images, txt, pdf on firebase storage by using FILE-URI distination (local path) ?

For example, How can I edit this uploading images function to upload files by using local path , and is possible to upload other types of files ?

```
private upload(): void {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Uploading..."
    })
    loader.present().then(_=>{
        return this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('Photo.JPEG')
        .putString(...NEED SOME HELP HERE....)
        .then((savedPicture) => {
            //--------------------------
            //--------------------------
        });
    }).then(_=>{
        loader.dismiss();
    })
}
```